# How to access nowrap element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to access the first input field from the below HTML, but unable to access the field. Find the HTML details as below:

```
<tr>
  <td>....</td>
  <td nowrap>
    <input type="text" name="details" id="details" value size="10" onfocus="doFieldFocusEvent(event)">
    <input type="hidden" id=details1 value>
 </td>
```

I have tried with the below approach but all returns false.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='details']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='details']"));
driver.findElement(By.id("details"));
driver.findElement(By.name("details"));
```

Can anyone help me to come out from this. Also can anyone give me idea on **nowrap** value.

Comment: *but all returns false*...`findElement()` return false?

Comment: what do you mean by all return false? Also are specifically looking for this element in `nowrap` td? Do the other `td` also contain similar element

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML code to me.  no equals for value in either input tag, id in second input tag not surrounded in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of relevant information got trimmed while you modified the actual *HTML* to present the the dummy *HTML* within the question. However a quick look at the attribute **onfocus="doFieldFocusEvent(event)"** confirms that the *HTML DOM* contains *Javascript* / *Ajax Calls*.

### HTML  nowrap Attribute

[**HTML  nowrap Attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp) attribute is a boolean attribute and when present it specifies that the content within the `<td>` cell **should not wrap**.

In the snapshot below the `<td>` element with **nowrap** attribute doesn't gets wrapped up while the `<td>` element without **nowrap** attribute gets wrapped up in absence of proper width/space.

[image: nowrap]

### Main Issue

I suspect your main issue is purely synchronization issue for which you have to induce *WebDriverWait*.

### Solution

While you lookout for this particular `<td>` element induce [WebDriverwait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in-conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause as [elementToBeClickable](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

```
WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='details']")));
```